# Why does KMeans have no attribute _inertia?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I read this and it didn't help: [AttributeError: 'KMeans' object has no attribute 'inertia_'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66681127/attributeerror-kmeans-object-has-no-attribute-inertia) . It says I need to call fit() and I'm doing that, but I still get the error.

This code was adapted from a JupyterLab Notebook so the line numbers in the error message, below, are incorrect.

```
aDF = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,5],[100,200,300,400,500]])
print (aDF)
wcss = []
for i in range(1, 11):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=i, random_state=0)
    kmeans.fit(aDF)
    wcss.append(kmeans.intertia_)
```

I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [102], in <cell line: 2>()
      3 kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=i, random_state=0)
      4 kmeans.fit(aDF)
----> 5 wcss.append(kmeans.intertia_)

AttributeError: 'KMeans' object has no attribute 'intertia_'
```

Comment: It looks like you misspelled `inertia_`.

Comment: Augh! Thanks! I will close this.