# AttributeError: 'KMeans' object has no attribute 'labels_' with pytorch

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, conv-neural-network, k-means, point-clouds

first of all I thank , I tried to train model with pytorch but I got the following error:
AttributeError: 'KMeans' object has no attribute 'labels_'.I am trying to model a extract features point cloud using deep learning in pytorch. I get the following error . Could anyone help on this? ************** *************** Thanks!

```
def forward(self, feature_matrix_batch):
        # feature_matrix_batch size = (N,I,D) where N=batch number, I=members, D=member dimensionality
        N, I, D = feature_matrix_batch.size()
        clusters = []
        for i, feature_matrix in enumerate(feature_matrix_batch):
            kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=self.k, init=self.kmeansInit, n_init=self.n_init)
            labels = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: x + (i*self.k), axis=0, arr=kmeans.labels_)
            clusters.extend(labels)
        clusters = np.asarray(clusters)
        list1 = []
        list2 = []
        for i in range(self.k*N):
            indices = np.argwhere(clusters == i).flatten().tolist()
            if len(indices) != 1:
                edges = [e for e in netx.complete_graph(indices).edges]
                inverse_edges = list(map(lambda x: (x[1], x[0]), edges))
                edges.extend(inverse_edges)
                unzip = list(zip(*edges))
                list1.extend(unzip[0])
                list2.extend(unzip[1])
            else:
                list1.append(indices[0])
                list2.append(indices[0])

        edge_index = torch.tensor([list1, list2], dtype=torch.long, device=getDevice(feature_matrix_batch))
        edge_index = sort_edge_index(add_self_loops(edge_index)[0])[0]
        conv_feature_matrix_batch = self.conv(feature_matrix_batch.view(-1, D), edge_index).view(N, I, -1)
        # conv_feature_matrix_batch size = (N,I,L) where N=batch number, I=members, L=C+P
        return feature_matrix_batch, conv_feature_matrix_batch, torch.tensor(clusters, dtype=torch.long, device=getDevice(feature_matrix_batch))
```

```
labels = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: x + (i*self.k), axis=0, arr=kmeans.labels_)
AttributeError: 'KMeans' object has no attribute 'labels_'
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi. Welcome to stackoverflow. Could you please include all the relevant `import` in your code? I am guessing maybe `import numpy as np; import torch; from sklearn import KMeans`; but it's easier for everyone if you don't make us guess

Comment: Also, could you please include a small example of `self` and `feature_matrix_batch` so that we can try running this `forward` function?

Comment: Otherwise we can't execute your code out of context and can't reproduce the error you got. See also [mre] for more information on how to write a question that can be more easily answered.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: 'KMeans' object has no attribute 'inertia\_'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66681127/attributeerror-kmeans-object-has-no-attribute-inertia)

Answer (score 1):

The attribute `labels_` of a `KMeans` object is created once you actually compute the clusters by running `.fit()` (or `.fit_predict()`, or `.fit_transform()`).

Simple example:

```py
>>> from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
>>> from numpy.random import random

>>> X = random((10,2))
>>> X
array([[0.2096706 , 0.69704806],
       [0.31732618, 0.29607599],
       [0.10372159, 0.56911046],
       [0.30922255, 0.07952464],
       [0.21190404, 0.46823665],
       [0.67134948, 0.95702692],
       [0.14781526, 0.24619197],
       [0.89931979, 0.96301003],
       [0.88256126, 0.07569739],
       [0.70776912, 0.92997521]])

>>> clustering = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
>>> clustering.labels_
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'KMeans' object has no attribute 'labels_'

>>> clustering.fit(X)
KMeans(n_clusters=3)
>>> clustering.labels_
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1], dtype=int32)
```